# How to add an arbitrary amount of time to duplicated dates in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, date, timedelta

I need to add a timedelta of an arbitrary amount to duplicated dates in a pandas DataFrame.

I have a dataframe where at most there are two rows with the same date per value of "area" and "date".
There is another column that tells me if it corresponds to the morning or evening.
I would like to add, lets say 8 hours to the dates corresponding to the evening rows.

So far I have managed to add a timedelta to the duplicated dates, but in this does not take into account if it is morning or evening.
Also in this way I cannot add an arbitrary timedelta amount.

Input df:

```
          date day_time  area  value
0   2019-02-13  evening     1   21.0232
1   2019-02-13  evening     2   28.5190
2   2019-02-13  evening     3   33.0943
3   2019-02-13  evening     4   21.9933
4   2019-02-14  evening     1   20.1975
5   2019-02-14  evening     2   34.5405
6   2019-02-14  evening     3   33.9600
7   2019-02-14  evening     4   29.9888
8   2019-02-14  morning     1   13.2533
9   2019-02-14  morning     2   25.2858
10  2019-02-14  morning     3   26.6155
11  2019-02-14  morning     4   21.9388
```

```py
time_delta = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(['date']).cumcount(), unit="h")
df['date'] = date['date'] + time_delta
```

Expected output:

```
                   date day_time  area  value
0   2019-02-13 08:00:00  evening     1   21.0232
1   2019-02-13 08:00:00  evening     2   28.5190
2   2019-02-13 08:00:00  evening     3   33.0943
3   2019-02-13 08:00:00  evening     4   21.9933
4   2019-02-14 08:00:00  evening     1   20.1975
5   2019-02-14 08:00:00  evening     2   34.5405
6   2019-02-14 08:00:00  evening     3   33.9600
7   2019-02-14 08:00:00  evening     4   29.9888
8   2019-02-14 00:00:00  morning     1   13.2533
9   2019-02-14 00:00:00  morning     2   25.2858
10  2019-02-14 00:00:00  morning     3   26.6155
11  2019-02-14 00:00:00  morning     4   21.9388
```

Comment: `df.loc[df.day_time  == 'evening', 'date'] += time_delta`?

Comment: That's it! That was easy haha :S